# BeautifulSoup webpage scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to scrap a webpage.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

page = requests.get('https://www.mql5.com/en/economic-calendar/united-states')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
calender = soup.find(id="economicCalendarTable")
items = calender.find_all(class_="ec-table__title")
print(items)
```

However, it prints an empty list, although in the webpage there are many entries with tag "class_="ec-table__title". What I found is that the tags inside "id="economicCalendarTable" tag are just in one line (very long). So, "calender.find_all" skips everything.

I am trying to get all tages inside 'id="economicCalendarTable"'.

Is there way to do this?

Comment: The page is dynamically generated, so when you use `requests` to download it, all those elements with `ec-table__title` aren't in the page source. If you want to, you can use [selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/installation.html#introduction), a code-controlled web browser, to wait for the page to load, and then scrape the page.

Comment: I do not see ec-table__title anywhere.
Where are those class located?

Comment: Just under id="economicCalendarTable" and below.

Comment: Ah, I see @manojg!
I've prepared a solution, you can find it below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `selenium`:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
d = webdriver.Chrome()
d.get('https://www.mql5.com/en/economic-calendar/united-states')
s = soup(d.page_source, 'lxml')
time = s.find('span', {'id':'economicCalendarTableColumnTime'}).text
title = s.find('div', {'class':'ec-table__title'}).text
classes = ['ec-table__col_time', 'ec-table__curency-name', 'ec-table__col_event', 'ec-table__col_forecast', 'prevValue']
full_data = [[i.find('div', {'class':c if c != 'prevValue' else re.compile('prevValue\d+')}) for c in classes] for i in s.find_all('div', {'class':'ec-table__item'})]
new_results = [dict(zip(['time', 'name', 'event', 'forcast', 'prevous_value'], [getattr(i, 'text', '') for i in b])) for b in full_data]
```

Output:

```
[{'event': u'Chicago Fed National Activity Index', 'forcast': u'0.14', 'name': u'USD', 'prevous_value': '', 'time': u' 08:30'}, {'event': u'Markit Manufacturing PMI', 'forcast': u'56.4', 'name': u'USD', 'prevous_value': '', 'time': u' 09:45'}, {'event': u'Markit Services PMI', 'forcast': u'55', 'name': u'USD', 'prevous_value': '', 'time': u' 09:45'}, {'event': u'Markit Composite PMI', 'forcast': u'55', 'name': u'USD', 'prevous_value': '', 'time': u' 09:45'}, {'event': u'New Home Sales m/m', 'forcast': u'-1.2%', 'name': u'USD', 'prevous_value': '', 'time': u' 10:00'}, {'event': u'New Home Sales', 'forcast': u'0.639 M', 'name': u'USD', 'prevous_value': '', 'time': u' 10:00'}, {'event': u'EIA Crude Oil Stocks Change', 'forcast': u'-1.791 M', 'name': u'USD', 'prevous_value': '', 'time': u' 10:30'}, {'event': u'EIA Cushing Crude Oil Stocks Change', 'forcast': u'0.259 M', 'name': u'USD', 'prevous_value': '', 'time': u' 10:30'}, {'event': u'EIA Crude Oil Imports Change', 'forcast': u'-0.32 M', 'name': u'USD', 'prevous_value': '', 'time': u' 10:30'}, {'event': u'EIA Distillate Fuel Production Change', 'forcast': u'-0.011 M', 'name': u'USD', 'prevous_value': '', 'time': u' 10:30'}, {'event': u'EIA Distillates Stocks Change', 'forcast': u'-0.182 M', 'name': u'USD', 'prevous_value': '', 'time': u' 10:30'}, {'event': u'EIA Gasoline Production Change', 'forcast': u'0.289 M', 'name': u'USD', 'prevous_value': '', 'time': u' 10:30'}, {'event': u'EIA Heating Oil Stocks Change', 'forcast': u'-0.026 M', 'name': u'USD', 'prevous_value': '', 'time': u' 10:30'}, {'event': u'EIA Gasoline Stocks Change', 'forcast': u'-3.206 M', 'name': u'USD', 'prevous_value': '', 'time': u' 10:30'}, {'event': u'FOMC Minutes', 'forcast': u'', 'name': u'USD', 'prevous_value': '', 'time': u' 14:00'}, {'event': u'Continuing Jobless Claims', 'forcast': u'1.769 M', 'name': u'USD', 'prevous_value': '', 'time': u' 08:30'}, {'event': u'Initial Jobless Claims', 'forcast': u'216 K', 'name': u'USD', 'prevous_value': '', 'time': u' 08:30'}, {'event': u'Initial Jobless Claims 4-Week Average', 'forcast': u'213.814 K', 'name': u'USD', 'prevous_value': '', 'time': u' 08:30'}, {'event': u'HPI m/m', 'forcast': u'0.5%', 'name': u'USD', 'prevous_value': '', 'time': u' 09:00'}, {'event': u'Existing Home Sales', 'forcast': u'5.45 M', 'name': u'USD', 'prevous_value': '', 'time': u' 10:00'}, {'event': u'Existing Home Sales m/m', 'forcast': u'0.3%', 'name': u'USD', 'prevous_value': '', 'time': u' 10:00'}, {'event': u'EIA Natural Gas Storage Change', 'forcast': u'92 B', 'name': u'USD', 'prevous_value': '', 'time': u' 10:30'}, {'event': u'Durable Goods Orders m/m', 'forcast': u'-0.3%', 'name': u'USD', 'prevous_value': '', 'time': u' 08:30'}, {'event': u'Core Durable Goods Orders m/m', 'forcast': u'0.0%', 'name': u'USD', 'prevous_value': '', 'time': u' 08:30'}, {'event': u'Durable Goods Orders excl. Defense m/m', 'forcast': u'-6.2%', 'name': u'USD', 'prevous_value': '', 'time': u' 08:30'}, {'event': u'Nondefense Capital Goods Orders excl. Aircraft m/m', 'forcast': u'0.3%', 'name': u'USD', 'prevous_value': '', 'time': u' 08:30'}, {'event': u'Fed Chair Powell Speech', 'forcast': u'', 'name': u'USD', 'prevous_value': '', 'time': u' 09:20'}, {'event': u'Michigan Consumer Sentiment', 'forcast': u'98.5', 'name': u'USD', 'prevous_value': '', 'time': u' 10:00'}, {'event': u'Michigan Consumer Expectations', 'forcast': u'88.9', 'name': u'USD', 'prevous_value': '', 'time': u' 10:00'}, {'event': u'Michigan Current Conditions', 'forcast': u'112.9', 'name': u'USD', 'prevous_value': '', 'time': u' 10:00'}, {'event': u'Michigan Inflation Expectations', 'forcast': u'2.7%', 'name': u'USD', 'prevous_value': '', 'time': u' 10:00'}, {'event': u'Michigan 5-Year Inflation Expectations', 'forcast': u'2.5%', 'name': u'USD', 'prevous_value': '', 'time': u' 10:00'}, {'event': u'Baker Hughes US Oil Rig Count', 'forcast': u'', 'name': u'USD', 'prevous_value': '', 'time': u' 13:00'}, {'event': u'CFTC Copper Non-Commercial Net Positions', 'forcast': u'', 'name': u'USD', 'prevous_value': '', 'time': u' 15:30'}, {'event': u'CFTC Crude Oil Non-Commercial Net Positions', 'forcast': u'', 'name': u'USD', 'prevous_value': '', 'time': u' 15:30'}, {'event': u'CFTC S&P 500 Non-Commercial Net Positions', 'forcast': u'', 'name': u'USD', 'prevous_value': '', 'time': u' 15:30'}, {'event': u'CFTC Gold Non-Commercial Net Positions', 'forcast': u'', 'name': u'USD', 'prevous_value': '', 'time': u' 15:30'}, {'event': u'CFTC Silver Non-Commercial Net Positions', 'forcast': u'', 'name': u'USD', 'prevous_value': '', 'time': u' 15:30'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no item with class `ec-table__title` in the base html of that page.

However, it does appear when using a dom inspector in the browser. I am afraid this is a sure sign that it has been inserted into the DOM by javascript ad indeed there is some javascript invoked by that webpage.

May I suggest that you investigate using the selenium module in conjunction with BeautifulSoup?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple example I've put together using Selenium and BeautifulSoup:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

# Selenium part
browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('https://www.mql5.com/en/economic-calendar/united-states')

# BeautifulSoup part
source = browser.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'html.parser')
calender = soup.find(id="economicCalendarTable")
items = calender.find_all(class_="ec-table__title")
print(items)
```

This code will allow you to download the page entirely and then pass the complete html source to BS

Be sure to install Selenium and the ChromeDriver correctly before running this script.